# QScrollBar Style Sheets - I think I need a multiple-direction gradient

Tags: css, qt

I would like to make a gradient for a QStyleSheet that does the following:
1) Transparent top 40%.
2) Opaque middle 20%, going from black to white.
3) Transparent bottom 40%.

A good example would be thinking of a 3-color flag, but I want the top and bottom transparent, and where the top and bottom are transparent, and the center is going from solid-black to white.

Basically I would like to somehow merge the following two linear gradients together, but I lack the knowledge to do so.

background-color: QLinearGradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1,
  stop:0.39 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
  stop:0.4 rgba(0,0,0,255),
  stop:0.6 rgba(0,0,0,255),
  stop:0.61 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
 );

and...

background-color: QLinearGradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
  stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255),
  stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)
 );

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to use a gradient to achieve this, but it would be difficult.

However, the easier way would be to override the style's drawing for the scroll bars, and paint your black/white gradient while clipping it to ensure the desired areas are still transparent.  Unfortunately, that solution doesn't rely solely on style sheets.

A third option, depending on your platform and capabilities, might be to create an image and set the background to that image, stretched (where necessary).